# DOM is not Updating When I am pushing an element into an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

I am using push method to adding an element into an array but DOM is not updating.

```html
<template>
  <td>
    <input
      :key="term"
      type="checkbox"
      :checked="
        term.payment_status != 'pending' ||
        (tenureAction == 'renew' &&
          key == 0 &&
          Object.keys(installments)[0] == index)
      "
      :disabled="term.payment_status != 'pending' || tenureAction == 'renew'"
      @click="setUnsetTermId(term.id)"
    />
  </td>
</template>
```

Comment: I've properly formatted your comment into a question. You're welcome.

Comment: Not sure where is the push method. More (well formatted) details are highly welcome here.

Comment: there's nothing in the template you've shown that suggests you have an Array to push into